# PhpStorm HTTP Client how can I get the actual request body after substituting dynamic variables?

Tags: intellij-idea, phpstorm, jetbrains-ide

When I use PhpStorm HTTP Client to send requests, I can see the full response body auto-saved to a file, and I can display or copy it.

My question is, how do I get the actual request body (like the response) after substituting dynamic variables?

I'm using PhpStorm `v2022.2.4` , with HTTP Client plugin v. `v222.4459.28`

Comment: This ticket is marked as fixed for 2022.3 version -- https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-291393. Should be in PhpStorm 2022.3. Please upgrade and check it there. Also: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-230756, https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-257965

Comment: Thank you @LazyOne ... upgrading to 2022.3 indeed solved the issue.

Answer (score 1):

> I'm using PhpStorm v2022.2.4 , with HTTP Client plugin v. v222.4459.28

The functionality you are after was implemented just recently (see the tickets below) and should be available in [just released 2022.3](https://blog.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/2022/12/phpstorm-2022-3-whats-new/) version. Please [upgrade your PhpStorm](https://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/download/) to the latest 2022.3 version and check it there.

Recently implemented tickets with related functionality:

- https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-291393
- https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-230756
- https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-257965